# Blazor Repeatable EventCallback for Menu Item

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

I am working on a repeatable "Card" component that has a list of menu items and actions that this menu can take.  However I cannot get the functionality to work.  I am coming from React where something like this is quite common but cannot convert my thinking to Blazor.  Help is appreciated.

**Parent Component:**

```cs
<Card Title="TestTitle" MenuActions=@MenuActions />

@code{

    public Dictionary<string, EventCallback> MenuActions = 
          new Dictionary<string, EventCallback>(){
            {"Test Case", HandleTestCase},
    }
    public void HandleTestCase(){
        Console.WriteLine("Test Case");
    }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```cs
<div>
<h2>@Title</h2>
<ul>
   @foreach(var(menuTitle, menuAction) in MenuActions) {
   <li>
      <button onclick=@(menuAction.Invoke())>
         @menuTitle
      </button> 
   </li>
   }
</div>

@code{

[Parameter]
public string Title {get; set;}

[Parameter]
public Dictionary<string, EventCallback> MenuActions {get; set;}

}
```

Totally lost, right now just getting this error:

```sh
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'
```

Comment: I guess you've made a call back to React, right ?

Answer (score 0):

First off some good documentation on the topic:

- [Components](https://blazor-university.com/components/)
- [ASP.NET Core Blazor event handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

It seems in your Child, you are **not** using the Blazor way to invoke an event, you are using HTML syntax, which would directly invoke JS code in the front end, oblivious to Blazor.

```
  <button onclick=@(menuAction.Invoke())>
     @menuTitle
  </button>
```

Note: `@onclick` vs `onclick`
mabye try:

```
  <button @onclick=MyMethod>
     @menuTitle
  </button> 
@code {
    void MyMethod() {
    //Invoke stuff here
    }
}
```

If you want to use JS-Interop read [this](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/).

Ofc you can load any JS code into the browser like with pure HTML and also write pure HTML to execute it, but with that you technically evade Blazor completely, like so:

```
onclick="console.log('Hello')"
```